# Doctrine Query Cache only for given application

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, query-cache

Is there any possibility to enable [Doctrine's Query Caching](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/caching%3aquery-cache-&-result-cache) for a given application?
Tried in Configuration.class.php, but without luck.

Comment: Isnt doctrine query caching enabled by default?

Comment: I guess im used to rails convention over configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your:

```
  public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
  {
    // Doctrine_Cache_Apc in the example
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, new Doctrine_Cache_Apc());
  }
```

to your:

```
/<project_path>/apps/<app_name>/config/<app_name>Configuration.class.php
```

Comment: Thanks, @samura. Did you test that? I tried exactly as you wrote, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I did try. But it gave me an error because I don't have APC installed, that means symfony read that method and it should work.